# how to solve ode: $x''(t)-k^2\cdot x(-t)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In this ordinary differential equation $$x''(t)-k^2\cdot x(-t)=0$$ both $x(t)$ and $x(-t)$ are included. I wonder whether this still is an ode and how to solve it.

I tried to use this property: $$x(t)=x_{odd}(t)+x_{even}(t)=\frac{x(t)-x(-t)}{2}+\frac{x(t)+x(-t)}{2}$$ to substitute $x(-t)$ but failed to get rid of "$-t$". Now I don't know how to continue the process.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The original equation is not an ordinary differential equation because of the $x(-t)$.  It is a [functional differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation).

Answer (score 3):

Write the first equation for $t$ and for $-t$:
$$x''(t)-k^2x(-t)=0\\x''(-t)-k^2x(t)=0$$
Now add them together, then subtract the two:
$$x''(t)+x''(-t)-k^2(x(t)+x(-t))=0\\x''(t)-x''(-t)-k^2(-x(t)+x(-t))=0$$
This yields $$x''_{even}(t)-k^2x_{even}(t)=0\\x''_{odd}(t)+k^2x_{odd}(t)=0$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Got the meaning! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

$x_{even}=[x(t)+x(-t)]/2$

$x_{odd}=[x(t)-x(-t)]/2$

$x(-t)=x_{even}-x_{odd}$

$x(t)=x_{even}+x_{odd}$

$x''_{even}+x''_{odd}-k^2(x_{even}-x_{odd})=0$

$x''_{even}-k^2x_{even}=0$

$x''_{odd}+k^2x_{odd}=0$

$x_{even}(t)=c_1e^{kt}+c_2e^{-kt}$

$x_{even}(t)=x_{even}(-t)\implies c_1e^{kt}+c_2e^{-kt}=c_1e^{-kt}+c_2e^{kt}\implies c_1=c_2$

So $x_{even}(t) = C\cosh (kt)$

$x_{odd}=b_1e^{ikt}+b_2e^{-ikt}$

$x_{odd}(t)=-x_{odd}(-t) \implies b_1e^{ikt}+b_2e^{-ikt}=-(b_1e^{-ikt}+b_2e^{ikt})\implies x_{odd}(t)=B\sin(kt) $

See if that works.

Comment: Yes! extremely grateful!!!